# Создать тихую установку программы

Tags: install, installshield

Есть установщик программы, по очереди выскакивают окна, на которые нужно дать ответ "да" или "нет". Как можно запрограммировать нажатия на ответы и сделать установку тихой? Чтобы при запуске файла проходила тихая установка, а ответы были даны по очереди так, как будет задано. Возможно ли вообще такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

[Да вот есть статья](http://nevor.ru/stati/operacionnye-sistemy/stati-dlya-windows/tihaya-ustanovka-prilozhenij-silent-install/), где подробно расписано про тихую установку, хотелось бы добавить, что это специфическое требование и больше подходит для системных администраторов или как пример установка свого bunle софта на чистую ОС, где тихая установка была бы не заменимой.... Так же можно использовать SFX архивы для этих задач.

Вот список бесплатных установщиков, которые поддерживаю создание тихих установщиков:

- Install Shield
- WISE Installer
- NSIS
- Inno Setup

Comment: Сам вопрос был о том, что как заставить окна делать "нажатия" при тихой установке. Обычные команды не позволяют полностью нормально установить, нужен клик пользователя именно в программе. О INNO и других подобных программах я прекрасно знаю, но имеется уже скомпилированный файл на INNO SETUP, а исходников нет.

Comment: я попробовал бы поискать в данном случае ключи запуска установщика через консоль командой /? /help и т.д., а вдруг повезет и данный установщик будет поддерживать тихую установку... что то наподобие этого: FILE_NAME.exe /VERYSILENT  или /SILENT

Comment: Сделано через INNO SETUP. Он поддерживает эти ключи для тихой установки, но там своё окно есть и при тихой установке оно не подтверждается, с остальными всё ок.